# linq perfomance, select specific columns or simply select all

Tags: c#, performance, linq

Performance wise, which one of those two is the fastest?

1. Simply using where clauses or select no columns etc.

   ```
   var products = db.Products.OrderByDescending(p => p.ProductExpirationDate);
   ```
2. Or More explicit with columns etc. as per this query

   ```
   var products = (from p in db.Products
   select new GenericEcomDataAccess.ProductView
   {
     ProductID = p.ProductID,
     ProductOwnerUserId = p.ProductOwnerUserId,
     ProductCurrency = p.ProductCurrency,
     ProductDescription = p.ProductDescription,
     ProductPrice = p.ProductPrice,
     ProductImage = p.ProductImage,
     ProductName = p.ProductName
   }).OrderByDescending(p => p.ProductExpirationDate).AsEnumerable().ToList();
   ```

Comment: Not sure and hence just a comment. Fact is it matters when you are writing T-SQL query. LINQ is just a wrapper and generates SQL query underneath. So I guess that should matter in LINQ too.

Comment: 1st one will return ``IQueryable<T>`` while the second one is ``List<T>``, better would be 1st approach, as it will take advantage of deffered execution

Comment: run each statement and look at the generated sql statements. if you're running against a large table, evaluate the performance and execution plan. Also, when you do materialize the data for #1, we have no idea what complex how object graph is. So it's hard to determine which one is better

Comment: Does [racing horse](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) proves or disproves your expectations? What kind of *performance* you mean? All is always takes more than subset (e.g. to transfer), but obtaining everything (not receiving!) is cheaper then doing something on each iteration.

Comment: It depends if you are pulling all the columns or not. Logically speaking, the fewer, the faster. However, you should always test them out with benchmarks. https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: It's impossible to say without more information. In isolation, the first one will execute faster because it doesn't actually do a query. Rather, it creates an object that will execute the query when you try to enumerate the result. The second one actually does the query and creates a list. Which is faster *in practice* largely depends on what you're going to do with it later.

Comment: actually after doing benchmark with system diagnostic the first one took 0 millisecond while the second option took 4 milliseconds. Quite fast but my data load was small. I guess the first one wins! Thats said I think we might have a reference for future interrogation. Mart

Comment: Add `.ToList()` to the first one and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, they produce different results (the second one uses `ToList()` which changes the result type).

Performance-wise, you didn't give enough info. It actually depends on your table. If the second query extracts every column for the table, they are the same. If not, the second one is *probably* faster (since sorting the part of the table takes less operation then sorting the whole of it).

But i would guess it doesn't actually matter since *asymptotically* they're the same. And if its not the performance-critical part of your program, my guess is you shouldn't actually care.

(And yes, since these queries are just SQL-statements inside, its better to ask this with SQL tag, not C#. Or at least add it to the tags).

Comment: thanx guys. I will benchmark later on when i have enough data but I guess I'll go with the fewer the better for now. Isolate a block of specific instead of getting many columns for nothing. Simplier to code but will it consume more resources and time?! I believe it should. Thx again. Mart